# Missing update button in Gradle file editor in IJ IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

How do I get this button to appear in my Gradle file editor panel in Intellij IDEA ?

[image]

I must have clicked on the `x` icon at some point, and lost it.

This button should appear when the code is modified with an impactful change (it does for Maven pom.xml files). As a workaround, I set automatic reloads for external changes in all build scripts, but I don't like it.

Comment: Even if you clicked `x` and closed this popup, it should appear automatically once the changes are detected by the IDE in the build file. If it's not happening, it's a bug that should be reported at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the steps to reproduce / sample project / logs.

Comment: I reproduce this behavior when modifying the script to add some non-impacting changes (e.g.:  adding some empty lines, or comments in the build script ) => refresh icon does not trigger in this case. as soon as I add some impacting changes, refresh button appears

Comment: Thank you @M.Ricciuti, I updated the post with the clarification.

Comment: This issue can also occur if you have enabled `external.system.auto.import.disabled` option in Help | Find Action | Registry. Please make sure it's not set to `true`.

Comment: Fixed by recloning the project from git and recreating a new project in IJ.

Answer (score 1):

It helped for me to disable and enable idea gradle plugin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).